# How to access java variables declared outside in flink map?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am creating a List in Java. I want to share the List within the map function in flink. How to share the variables across flink processes

Requirement
I have static data records(Less than 1000 records). I want to join these records with the data stream.

Answer (score 0):

Flink is designed with scalability in mind, and so it embodies a *share nothing* approach. An operator can be stateful, but its state is strictly local and not visible to other operators.

In this particular case, a good solution might be to use a `RichMapFunction` (or `RichFlatMapFunction`) to do the join, and to load a copy of all of the static data records into a local transient data structure in its `open` method.

Comment: Requirement I have static data records(Less than 1000 records). I want to join these records with the data stream.

Comment: How to join static data with a streaming data flink?